# Cocos2D: how to tweak CCMenuItem with only one sprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, ccmenuitem

how could I tweak CCMenuItemSprite to support only one sprite?

Currently I have:

```
[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:one selectedSprite:selectedOne]
```

But would like to have:

```
[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:one]
```

**EDIT: I want to modify CCMenuItem to work only with one CCSprite and not two. So I need to change also the internal methods.**

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the same (normal) sprite as the selected sprite. When clicked, the button will then do nothing.

Comment: yeah but I is not neat, the two sprites have different beheaviour and animations and include some touchable items

Comment: @mm24 I am not understanding the question well then. You said you only wanted to support one sprite for a `CCMenuItem`. However, the methods need to support both unselected and selected sprites. Are you using the menu in another way?

Comment: Added an edit, I need to change the code of CCMenuItem but wanted to have some quick hints before.. I will post my attempt soon.

Comment: @mm24 I think your undertaking to modify the code is not the best solution. FYI cocos2D caches textures in memory - so providing the same image as the selected does not add a second sprite. I guess I am confused about exactly what you are trying to accomplish that could only need one sprite when this works just as well and is simple

Answer (score 1):

You could just use

```
[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:one selectedSprite:one]
```

this way, nothing would happen when you select the sprite

Comment: yeah but I is not neat, the two sprites have different beheaviour and animations and include some touchable items

Answer (score 0):

try this, just change colour of seleted sprite.

```
CCSprite *sprite1   = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Button.png"];
CCSprite * sprite2  = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Button.png"];
sprite2.color = ccc3(128, 128, 128);

CCMenuItemImage *itemEasyLevelImage = [CCMenuItemImage  itemWithNormalSprite:sprite1
                                                              selectedSprite:sprite2
                                                                       block:^(id sender){}];
```

Comment: That's not what I need to do, I wanted to use only one Sprite :) and not have 2 sprites :)

Comment: ok..that's gud idea..One thing is even if u create 2 sprite with same image then cocos2d just creates single openGL texture and loading of this happens only once. So I can say you just targeting fraction's of fractional memory and time :P